# invalid read with fprintf

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

I'm currently working on a project and one of the given functions seems to compile fine but doesn't work properly.

```
    void tsunamiWriteFile(const char *baseResultName, int iter, double *U, double *V, double *E, int nelem, int nsub){
    int i,j;
    const char *basename = "%s-%08d.txt";
    char filename[256];
    sprintf(filename,basename,baseResultName,iter);
    FILE* file = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(file, "Number of elem %d \n", nelem);
    ...
    ... }
```

When i run the program with valgrind, i get this:

```
    ==4993== Invalid read of size 4
    ==4993==    at 0x59D3778: __fprintf_chk (fprintf_chk.c:32)
    ==4993==    by 0x4081B4: tsunamiWriteFile (stdio2.h:98)
    ==4993==    by 0x408363: tsunamiCompute (tsunami.c:228)
    ==4993==    by 0x401714: main (mainCompute.c:10)
    ==4993==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

any idea why fprintf don't work?

Comment: You need to check that the file is actually opened.

Comment: There is no error in you code that I can see, but you're not checking if the file you tried to open actually opened. Most likely, there is some error in the formatting of the string such that it looks for a file that doesn't exist. When you then try to print to it, it'll throw this error.

Comment: @Yellow: I'd consider not testing the result of relevant system calls to **be** an error (in the code).

Answer (score 4):

The error :

```
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd.
```

Indicates that a `NULL` pointer has been received and the function tried to dereference it.

You need to check the pointer that `fopen` returns you :

```
if ((file = fopen(filename, "w")) != NULL)
    fprintf(file, ...);
else
    perror("fopen");
```